# Bind Screen shortcut to Ctrl+Q without prefix

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I want to create a screen shortcut `^q` to detach from the current session.
In Tmux I would use `bind -n` command.

In screen I'v tried:

- `bind q detach` works with prefix as `C-a q`
- `bind ^q detach` doesn't work at all

Is that even possible to bypass prefix in the screen so simple `C-q` could work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You chose a difficult character. For example, if you had tried <kbd>Control-P</kbd> it would have been a bit easier, ie (using `bindkey` not `bind`):

```
bindkey ^p detach
```

and it would have worked. You can try the same with `^q` and it probably won't seem work. The problem is that <kbd>Control-Q</kbd> is also used by your tty to do flow-control (xon/xoff). As you probably are not interested in flow-control, you could disable it in your tty with the shell command

```
stty -ixon
```

and then <kbd>Control-Q</kbd> should work.

Comment: Work's like a charm. I'm sure I don't need the flow control. And after checking what it exactly is I know what was causing my terminal "freezes" from time to time. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue, was trying to pass ctrl+q through to tmux over serial inside screen (don't ask), weird that it works via tmux or ssh normally, just screen being picky I guess?